# Is it possible to resolve ADFS 3.0 claims for a given identifier without logging in?

Tags: sharepoint, claims-based-identity, adfs3.0

I'm having to debug claims in production and I have no idea which claims a user have. This is a SharePoint application.

Given a username, is it possible for ADFS/DC/whatever to give me the claims that would be associated with that user? If so, how?

- I can have the IT guy run something (configuration, exe, etc.) in production (very quick)
- I can redeploy the whole application including debug code to extract claims (days)

I've already done #2 in the past. I'm wondering if ADFS has an command line or a menu somewhere that would provide me that information.

Comment: If you don't have enough information to investigate the bug, isn't the best course of action to get more information from the reporter? Also, why does it take days to deploy your application? That sounds like a non-trivial business risk to have.

Comment: Days because the processes are long. They will need to retest everything and bring everything to DEV/QA and finally production. As for access, they do not grant access the developers access to data since it's about the payroll and anything I would normally do to debug isn't available to me.

Comment: What I'm trying to do in that case is... "Resolve the claims for an identifier". I think I got the jargon right. I'm still Googling...

Comment: Ah, I thought a "claim" was domain-specific terminology, like in insurance - however just noticed your tagging. OK, no idea - perhaps someone else will be able to make suggestions.

Comment: @halfer no biggies. Trying 25 different stuff on this. Been stuck on this problem for a few days.

Comment: @MaximeRouiller-MVP What exactly do you mean when you say you want to resolve or get the claims for a user? That is, do you want to know what access they have in the SharePoint application? Do you want to see their SAML token? Are you curious about which claims provider generated their token?

Comment: My end goal is to have their claims so I can see what roles that they have but not from the context of AD but from the application's perspective (who only receive claims).

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from taking the claims rules configured for an RP, mapping them to AD attributes and then running an LDAP query against AD for that user. You don't need specific user logins to do this. This would only work for "internal" users. You wouldn't be able to see claims for users who federated from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

After [talking with Dominick Baier on Twitter](https://twitter.com/leastprivilege/status/705485116261470208) (author of IdentityServer), that feature apparently doesn't exist. So I'll mark this as answered and move on with my life and find some other ways to fix this problem.

**Screenshot of the conversation:**

[image: screenshot]